# SUM numbers in a nested list

Tags: python-3.x, nested-loops

Currently I am trying to sum numbers from two nested loops. I am very close but for some reason, the numbers are not adding properly.

```
def addTables(table1,table2):
counter = 0
index = 0
table3 = [[None] * len(table1[0])] * len(table1)
print(table3)
for row in table1:
    for i in table1[0]:
        table3[counter][index] = table1[counter][index] + table2[counter][index]
        index = index +1
    index = 0
    counter = counter + 1
    print (table3)
```

My values are `table1 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]` and `table2 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]`.
For some reason, it is printing

```
[[None, None, None], [None, None, None]]
[[2, 4, 6], [2, 4, 6]]
[[8, 10, 12], [8, 10, 12]]
```

but i want it to print

```
[[None, None, None], [None, None, None]]
[[2, 4, 6], [None, None, None]]
[[2, 4, 6], [8, 10, 12]]
```

I think this line is wrong, but I have no idea how to fix it.

`table3[counter][index] = table1[counter][index] + table2[counter]`

Comment: i believe you are using the wrong terminology here. by sum do you mean you want to add the nests elemenwise (or matrix addition)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in

```
table3 = [[None] * len(table1[0])] * len(table1)
```

Multiplying a list actually copies references to its items; it doesn't duplicate the items in the list. To see what happens, look at your code like this:

```
subtable = [None] * len(table1[0])]
# subtable = [None, None, None]
table3 = [subtable] * len(table1)
# table3 = [subtable, subtable]
```

Thus, `table3[0]` and `table3[1]` are actually the same list. So when you set `table3[0][0]`, you're actually modifying `subtable`, which is `table3[0]` and `table3[1]`!

You can see this effect for yourself:

```
>>> table3 = [[None] * 3] * 2
>>> table3
[[None, None, None], [None, None, None]]
>>> table3[0][1] = 5
>>> table3
[[None, 5, None], [None, 5, None]]
```

You can fix this by using [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to construct `table3`:

```
>>> table3 = [[None for x in table1[0]] for y in table1]
>>> table3
[[None, None, None], [None, None, None]]
>>> table3[0][1] = 5
>>> table3
[[None, 5, None], [None, None, None]]
```

Alternatively, using list multiplication for the inner list is fine. (This is because the references to `None` get replaced, while references to a sublist get modified in place):

```
>>> table3 = [[None] * len(table1[0]) for y in table1]
>>> table3
[[None, None, None], [None, None, None]]
>>> table3[0][1] = 5
>>> table3
[[None, 5, None], [None, None, None]]
```

This subtlety may be confusing though. Using a nested list comprehension is more explicit.

But personally, I wouldn't construct the list ahead of time like that in the first place. Instead, I would recommend starting with an empty list, and appending to that as you go

```
table3 = []
for row in table1:
    sumrow = []
    index = 0
    for i in table1[0]:
        sumrow.append(table1[counter][index] + table2[counter][index])
        index += 1
    table3.append(sumrow)
    counter += 1
```

And, building upon that, it's usually cleaner to iterate over lists directly, rather than iterating over their indices. You can iterate over two equally-sized lists by using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), like so:

```
for row1, row2 in zip(table1, table2):
    sumrow = []
    for item1, item2 in zip(row1, row2):
        sumrow.append(item1 + item2)
    table3.append(sumrow)
```

And once we're there, we could express `sumrow` as a list comprehension:

```
for row1, row2 in zip(table1, table2):
    table3.append([item1 + item2 for item1, item2 in zip(row1, row2)])
```

Note that this pairwise addition in the list comprehension can also be achieved by applying [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) to every pair using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
for row1, row2 in zip(table1, table2):
    table3.append(list(map(sum, zip(row1, row2))))
```

And then we could also replace the outer for loop by a list comprehension.

```
table3 = [list(map(sum, zip(row1, row2))) for row1, row2 in zip(table1, table2)]
```

Which can be slightly improved by using list unpacking for the rows:

```
table3 = [list(map(sum, zip(*rows))) for rows in zip(table1, table2)]
```

I'm a little conflicted if this is actually the best / most readable approach, so maybe I should've stopped a few versions ago. But hey, here we are ;)

Comment: Thank you so much! I know that the approach is very unorthodox but it's for practice. Thank you for clearing things up about the list composition.